# Как сделать так, чтобы линии визуально выглядели одинаково?

Tags: html, css, display

Имеются два одинаковых раздела, состоящие из заголовка, псевдоэлемента к этому заголовку и абзаца. Если задать внешний отступ, то линии начинают визуально отличаться.

Вот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*------------------------*/
.block-1{
  padding: 108px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.block-1 h2{
  color: #212121;
}
.block-1 h2::after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin: 29px auto 0 auto;
  height: 2px;
  width: 64px;
  background-color: #ff9142;
}
.block-1 p{
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
  }

/*-------------------------*/
.block-2{
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 108px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.block-2 h2{
  color:  #000;
}
.block-2 h2::after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
    height: 2px;
    width: 64px;
    background-color: #ff9142;
}
.block-2 p{margin: 30px 0 0 0;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href='test.css'>
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="block-1">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Why this is awesome</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block-2">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Why this is awesome</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: В чем именно заключается "некорректность"? Вроде все правильно и ожидаемо в таком результате добавления маржина.

Comment: Если ты о проделках субпиксельного рендеринга, из-за которого линия визуально тоньше становится - то это надо конкретизировать в вопросе... Да и если не об этом, вопрос в любом случае надо дополнить более точным указанием на проблему.

Comment: @yar85 Да, проблема заключается в том, что визуально линия становится тоньше. Именно это я подразумевал под "некорректностью"

Comment: С субпиксельным рендером ничего поделать не получится. Можно только подобрать значения, которые будут лучше выглядеть.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение

Comment: @nazarpunk, можно попробовать-посмотреть `image-rendering` или хак через `calc`, и т.д.. Это же стили, они гибкие: какой-нибудь костыль да поможет :) но тут в ответах мы вряд ли увидим варианты, т.к. ТС ленится улучшать вопрос (so do I).

Comment: стили то гибкие, но рендеринг от устройства к устройству отличается. Единственный способ избежать такого, это указание размера в единицах, которые не приведутся в дробные значения пикселя. Учитывая пользовательское масштабирование, это практически невозможно.

Comment: @nazarpunk, да, если будет масштабирование - то никак, в этом ты прав абсолютно. Но при 100% масштабе, думаю можно найти "стабильный" вариант, по крайней мере есть смысл попытаться... @Игорь, спасибо за уточнение вопроса (`▲`).

Comment: При 100% масштабе достаточно в решиме разработчика убедиться, что рендериться целое значение пикселя. И желательно на устройстве с `devicePixelRatio=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже что использование `border` вместо `background` для создания линий подчеркивания заголовка, в данном случае - устраняет визуальные различия (из-за субпиксельного рендеринга) между сдвинутыми и несдвинутыми псевдоэлементами. Включая случаи масштабирования документа "вверх".

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
 /*-------------------------*/
.block-1    { padding: 50px 0; text-align: center; }
.block-1 p  { margin: 30px 0 0 0; }
.block-1 h2 { color: #212121; }
/*-------------------------*/
.block-2    { padding: 50px 0; text-align: center; background-color: #f5f5f5; }
.block-2 p  { margin: 30px 0 0 0; }
.block-2 h2 { color: #000; }
/*-------------------------*/
.block-1 h2::after,
.block-2 h2::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 0;                        /* ◄◄◄ */
  width: 64px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff9142; /* ◄◄◄ */
}

.block-2 h2::after { margin-top: 30px; }
```

```html
<div class="block-1">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Why this is awesome</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block-2">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Why this is awesome</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[GIF демо](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su8Qn.jpg)

Просьба опровергнуть решение, если оно не помогает (указав браузер в котором проблема все же осталась) в комментариях к ответу... я проверил только в Chrome для Linux.

---

*// Для проверки масштабирования примера, его надо развернуть на всю страницу после нажатия кнопки "Выполнить код".*

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает (Chrome, FireFox, Edge, Yandex -  на Windows, остальные не проверял )